# Getting audio information using MediaInfo

Tags: script, shell-script, media-info

So if I have a file with audio with the following properties:

Language: English

Bitrate: 1509 kb/s

Sampling Rate: 48.0 kHz

Bit Depth: 24 bits

Channels: 6

Format: DTS

I have wrote the following to extract this information:

```
MediaInfo "--Output=Audio;%Language/String%, $if(%BitRate%, %BitRate%/1000 kb/s), $if(%SamplingRate%, %SamplingRate% kHz), $if(%BitDepth%, %BitDepth% bits), $if(%"Channel(s)"%, %"Channel(s)"% channels), %Format%" File.mkv
```

This is the output I get:

```
English,  1509000/1000 kb/s,  48000 kHz,  24 bits, %, 6 channels), DTS
```

So I can see 3 main issues here. It's showing in bits rather than kilobits. How can I get it to divide by 1000? Issue 2: Same for kHz need to divide by 1000. Third issue is after the bit depth I have a random % and ) left over which I assume is to do with the "channel(s)" thing already including brackets.

If anyone could help me solve this I would greatly appreciate it. This is my first time using a CLI tool so I am not great.

Answer (score 1):

MediaInfo template feature was a "proof of concept", checking if some people were interested in that, and it has a couple of flaws, including bugs in the template parser i.e. the extra ")" in the output should not be there.
Also you can use some formatting integrated in MediaInfo e.g. using Kb/s or Mb/s when relevant.

```
MediaInfo.exe "--Output=Audio;[%Language/String%, ][%BitRate/String%, ][%SamplingRate/String%, ][%BitDepth/String%, ][%"Channel(s)/String"%, ]%Format%" --Language="  Config_Text_ThousandsSeparator;" File.mkv
```

Example of result:

```
French, 2185 kb/s, 48.0 kHz, 16 bits, 6 channels, DTS
```

If you need a more advanced formatting feature, you need to use e.g. the XML output then process it throw an external formatting tool e.g. XSLT.

Jérôme, main developer of MediaInfo.

Comment: +1 One question related to this: "including bugs in the template parser i.e. the extra ")" in the output should not be there." Why have you not removed the extra ")" in subsequent release(s)?

Comment: For anyone reading this who is doing the same as me, trying to get it to work with Batch. Do double percent tags %%ETC%%, %%ETC2%%